# LXD Connect to a container on public ip

Tags: server, ip, lxd, container

So I've setup a Ubuntu server 18.04.01 64bit can connect to it and all that with SSH.

Installed LXD/LXC

I also created a bridge br0 in netplan with DHCP at first an to connect to the containers with SSH and it worked great local.

Then I wanted to do it puclic IP style to connect to one container or multiple I disabled dhcp4 and 6 og both  eth0 and br0 and set static IP on br0 to public IP in netplan! For the host part I can connect to the server directly but not the container and that is what I want to.

I already tried setting up SSH on the container on port 23 and static IP is the same as host but I cannot connect with that.

How can I do so I can connect directly to the container with the user created on there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

`lxc config device add <container-name> sshproxy proxy listen=tcp:<public-ip>:23 connect=tcp:<container-ip>:22 bind=host`

if your container runs ssh on standard port 22. Get  and  with `lxc list`, get the  with `ifconfig`

Cheers